# How to set an HTTP header on a request to avoid HTTP authentication?

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, http-headers, cisco

I have  an HTTP authentification that appears every time I try to get access to my Cisco switch.

After analysing packets using Wireshark I figured out that I need somehow to put a header containing my basic HTTP authentification so I can avoid retyping it every single time (I have so many switches and I am currently developing a tool  for network managing).

What i want to say , I want to somehow make my authentification using only one single button

PS : i am beginner at JavaScript I dont use it alot

Thanks

Comment: I have googled `how to set a http header` and it lead me to this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Setting_HTTP_request_headers

Answer (score 0):

You have to allow Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) request to pass the authentication.

Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that uses additional HTTP headers to let a user agent gain permission to access selected resources from a server on a different origin (domain) than the site currently in use. A user agent makes a cross-origin HTTP request when it requests a resource from a different domain, protocol, or port than the one from which the current document originated.

If you want to check if it works or not you can use this [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)